# Session being destroyed on remote server, but ok on local version of site

Tags: php, session

I have a local and remote version of a CMS I've built on top of a PHP framework - in the local version of the site, my authentication session works absolutely fine when I check it from a couple of 3rd party modules integrated into the site, however, in the remote site the session is always destroyed whenever I try to check it from any of these modules, which breaks my authentication handling. The code is identical, so I'm guessing that this isn't anything to do with the framework, more to do with the server environment.

The session config in php.ini is the same for both my local and remote servers. My local version of PHP is 5.3, while the remote version is 5.2.9, but I don't think that would be affecting this issue.

Has anyone any ideas what this could potentially be related to?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about the difference in versions not being important, 5.3 made a TON of changes.

Comment: I'm not sure this is it or help but I had a similar issue on Ubuntu, here is the post: http://llihp.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-are-my-php-sessions-timing-out.html

Answer (score 0):

Can the web server write to wherever session data is configured to be stored?  (usually the /tmp directory, but could be set to a different location in the php.ini file).  Is the browser accepting the session cookie?

Comment: Yes the session data is being stored fine - however, when I try to check the session data from outside the scope of the framework (e.g in a photo gallery on the same domain but in a different directory), it has been destroyed. The weird thing is that this only happens remotely, not locally

Comment: The data is accessible within the framework but not from outside it, is that correct?  You might want to edit your question to include that fact. :)  Can you check the cookie that PHP sets to see what domain and path it has?  For the cookie to be recognised it's got to have the same domain (if you have foo.example.com and bar.example.com then an example.com domain cookie will work on both but a foo.example.com will only work on the first), and the scripts trying to access it have to be in the same path.  If the path set in the cookie is /foo/bar/ then something in /foo cant access it.